# Selecting Specific Dates in R

Tags: r, date, subset

I am wondering how to create a subset of data in R based on a list of dates, rather than by a date range.

For example, I have the following data set `data` which contains 3 years of 6-minute data.

```
      date            zone month day year hour minute temp speed gust dir 
1  09/06/2009 00:00   PDT     9   6 2009    0      0   62    2   15 156 
2  09/06/2009 00:06   PDT     9   6 2009    0      6   62   13   16 157
```

I have used `breeze<-subset(data, ws>=15 & wd>=247.5 & wd<=315, select=date:dir)` to select the rows which meet my criteria for a sea breeze, which is fine, but what I want to do is create a subset of the days which contain those times that meet my criteria.

I have used...

```
as.character(breeze$date)
trimdate<-strtrim(breeze$date, 10)
breezedate<-as.Date(trimdate, "%m/%d/%Y")
breezedate<-format(breezedate, format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

...to extract the dates from each row that meets my criteria so I have a variable called `breezedate` that contains a list of the dates that I want (not the most eloquent coding to do this, I'm sure). There are about two-hundred dates in the list. What I am trying to do with the next command is in my original dataset `data` to create a subset which contains only those days which meet the seabreeze criteria, not just the specific times.

```
breezedays<-(data$date==breezedate)
```

I think one of my issues here is that I am comparing one value to a list of values, but I am not sure how to make it work.

Comment: A side-note: an alternative way to a date variable could be `as.Date(paste(year, month, day, sep = "-"))`. Or: `datetime <- as.POSIXct(date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"); as.Date(datetime)`

Comment: Or: `trunc(as.POSIXct(date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), unit = "days")`

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume your breezedate list looks like this and data$date is simple string:

```
  breezedate <- as.Date(c("2009-09-06", "2009-10-01"))
```

This is probably want you want:

```
  breezedays <- data[as.Date(data$date, '%m/%d/%Y') %in% breezedate]
```

Comment: So I got it to work and yours was the closest to what it needed to be. I first had to make sure both data variables were the same class, then I cut down the date variable (removing the hour and minute from the end of the variable) and saved it as another column so i was comparing apples to apples (data$date1 <- trunc(data$date,units="days")), then I used  breezedays <- subset( data, data$date1 %in% breezedate) and I got a new dataframe called breezedays with two date columns, date and date1, one with the correct dates and one with the correct dates/times. Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

The `intersect()` function ([docs](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sets.html)) will allow you to compare one data frame to another and return those records that are the same.

To use, run the following:

```
breezedays <- intersect(data$date,breezedate) # returns into breezedays all records that are shared between data$date and breezedate
```

Comment: I understand the logic behind this, but since breezedate looks like "09-06-2009" and data$date looks like "09-06-2009 1:55", so the program isn't recognizing that there are any similarities between the two.