# How to select values for specific dates

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to know how I can select data for specific dates.
For example, I wrote this code.

```
dt = data.table(Date = as.Date(c("2016-01-01", "2016-02-01", "2016-03-01", "2016-04-01", "2016-05-01")), 
                Value = c(1,2,3,4,5) )

dates = as.Date(c("2016-02-01", "2016-03-01"))

result = dt[Date == dates]
```

I'd like to get the values for "2016-02-01", "2016-03-01"

I tried to write that, but this code does not work.

```
result = dt[Date == dates]
```

Comment: Did you look at this so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725014/selecting-specific-dates-in-r  Found by searching "r select date from list"

Answer (score 1):

You last line of code could be this:

```
result = dt$Value[dt$Date %in% dates]
# [1] 2 3
```